# How to add article page url at bottom of the same page?

Tags: wordpress, article

I started an article directory in word press. I want to add article url at the end of the same page.
How to write that code.
for example http://ezinearticles.com/?Motorcycle-Audio---Accessorize-With-A-Helmet-With-Speakers&id=6279817
here at the end url is given.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options for that:

The WordPress way would be to use get_permalink($post_id)

```
<?php
global $post
$link = get_permalink($post->ID);
```

or you could use the REQUEST_URI shown here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-current-page-url

Comment: Ben i don`t have any idea about where I can find permalink and where to write. So please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I got just add this code in single.php page after content() you will get<?php the_permalink() ?>